# Siverlight: PageVisual - Element is already a child of another element

Tags: silverlight, exception, printing, parent-child

I'm currently trying to print a Silverlight form but I get an exception each time i try to set the PageVisual saying that "Element is already a child of another element". I understand that I cannot change the parent of a given control, but here i'm not setting a different parent, I'm simply setting the PageVisual. Is there a work around to print my controls ?

Here's my code below:

```
              private void PrintOrExport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();


        Common.MDivDegreeReqNew mymdiv = scrllvwr.Content as Common.MDivDegreeReqNew;

        document.PrintPage += (s, args) =>
            {

                Grid GridToBePrinted = new Grid();
                GridToBePrinted.Height = 0;
                if (mymdiv.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Count == 0)
                {
                    //break;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < mymdiv.LayoutRoot.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    // if GridToBePrinted height + this rows height is less than the PrintableArea heigh
                    // then add this row to the gridtobeprinted.
                    if (GridToBePrinted.Height + mymdiv.LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[i].ActualHeight < args.PrintableArea.Height)
                    {
                        Grid mygrid = new Grid();

                        mygrid =(Grid) mymdiv.LayoutRoot.Children[i];
                        //mymdiv.LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(mygrid);
                        GridToBePrinted.Children.Add(mygrid);
                        i--;

                        GridToBePrinted.Height += mygrid.ActualHeight;

                        if (mymdiv.LayoutRoot.Children.Count == 0)
                        {
                            args.PageVisual = GridToBePrinted;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        args.PageVisual = GridToBePrinted;
                        if (mymdiv.LayoutRoot.Children.Count > 0)
                        {
                            args.HasMorePages = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            args.HasMorePages = false;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                } 
            };
        document.Print(name+ " - MDiv Requirements");
```

Edit --
The code is updated, this code also creates the same exception. Instead of using the scrollview content, creating a new instance of MDivDegreeReqNew produces 0 Height form and the printing page is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a grid inside your layout root, then adding the controls that you wish to print to this grid:

Create a grid.

```
  <Grid  Margin="0,46,0,0" Name="PrintingRegion" Visibility="Visible" Height ="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
  </Grid>
```

Then add your UI elements that you wish to print

```
Printingregion.Children.add...
```

Apply any transformations (if needed)

```
  PrintingRegion.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup
```

Then set your page visual to print

```
  e.PageVisual = PrintingRegion
```

----Edit----- Actually i think the problem that you are having is that your layout root has 2 children, i think you can only set the page visual when there is one child. If you need to print both the label and the canvas, wrap them both in another canvas and then add this canvas to your grid. Then you will have one child with all the UI elements that you require

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is, the controls to be printed are in another form where each set of controls are contained in a grid. This form can span more than one page and so I need to add the children grids one by one to my Printingregion and check the height each time if it's greater than the PrintableArea Height. 
I tried creating a new instance of the form to be printed and remove the child grid from that form before adding to the Printingregion but the newly created instance of my form actually has a Height of 0 and printed nothing. 
I updated my question with my detailed code.

Comment: Okay i get you - so why not add the whole form to the printing region. Then you can check the `PrintingRegion.DesiredSize.Height` and then set the `args.HasMorePages` appropriately. Ive done a similar thing and if the form to print requires more than one page i adjust the x and y values with a transformation to "shift up" the form so that the next part will fit on. If you get what i mean

Comment: But how will you "cut" the form at a specific place ? I mean with shifting up the form this will ensure I got the correct start, but what about the ending, will the form be cut randomly at the end ?

Comment: You don't need to cut it, as your whole form will be one UI element - Your just shifting the next part into view. The printer will only print what will fit on one page & you know the size of what will fit from the calculation, from there you can plan where the printer will cut. It's a bit of trial and error at first

Comment: I used the first way you suggested and worked around the Height problem by using two instances of my form. A newly created instance is used to fill my "PrintingRegion" by cutting and pasting the row to it. The existing instance in the ScrollViewer is used to set the height of the PrintingRegion, since the first instance would give height=0.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ah right yeah i see. Seems a good way to do it. No problem, glad i could help